# Resilience4j: what exactly does waitDuration accomplish?

Tags: java, kotlin, timeout, resilience4j

Regarding this example: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-5

```
RetryConfig config = RetryConfig.custom()
.maxAttempts(2)
.waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(100))
.retryOnResult(response -> response.getStatus() == 500)
.retryOnException(e -> e instanceof WebServiceException)
.retryExceptions(IOException.class, TimeoutException.class)
.ignoreExceptions(BusinessException.class, OtherBusinessException.class)
.build();
```

what exactly does `waitDuration` accomplish? Does it mean to timeout and retry after 100 ms? Or does it mean how long to wait before next retry?

Comment: I found it in the documentation